# Create a custom popup in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, popup

Is it possible with Flutter to create a component that opens upon clicking a button, like a popup, but with the ability to still use the already opened background page?

Another possibility is to resize the component.

Comment: Can you try Dialog/ AlertDialog widget ?

Answer (score 0):

of course you can use general dialog to get the desired result.. just add these lines upon onTap/onPressed callback function

```
  showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      pageBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2) =>
          const SizedBox(height: 0.0, width: 0.0),
      transitionBuilder: (context, animation, secAnimation, child) {
        
        return Dialog(child: CUSTOMWIDGET(),  );
          
      },
      barrierDismissible: true,
      barrierLabel: 'dialog',
    );
```

where CUSTOMWIDGET is the widget you wanna show upon click